# how to get game to restart when user types 'yes'?

Tags: python

how do I make it restart when the user types "yes"

```
import random



answer=(random.randint (1,100))
play_again="yes"

tries=(0)``

guess=int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100 "))

tries+=1

while play_again=="yes":

if (guess<answer):
    guess=int(input("its higher than "+str(guess)+" "))
    tries+=1
elif (guess>answer):
    guess=int(input("it's lower than "+str(guess)+" "))
    tries+=1
elif (guess==answer):
        print("well done! You guessed the number in "+str(tries)+" guesses!")
        play_again=input("would you like to play again?")
```

how do I make the game restart after the user wins when they type "yes"?

Comment: Accept for the indentation, what is wrong with your code?

Comment: it ends the loop whether I type yes or no. I did have more typed after play_again input, but it wasn't working at all and has the same result as it does now.

Answer (score 0):

use two loops. one outer with `play_again == "yes"` and one inner with `guess != answer`.

```
while play_again == "yes":
    # get input
    while guess != answer:
        # if lower:
        #     get guess
        # if higher
        #     get guess
    # get play_again
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this , create a function !

```
import random
import sys 

def main():

    # your code here

while True:
   play_again = input("play again? :") # For python 2 raw_input()
   if play_again == "yes":
         main()
   else:
        sys.exit()
```

Something like this !

I hope this helps you!!

Comment: if I move it to the right indention, it says either answer,play_again and tries is not defined, if I move it further back, it says I have an indented block? how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

With a function that calls itself

```
def main():

    # your code goes here

    if input('Play again?') == 'yes':
        main()
```